# Sorting words in p tags from HTML collection

Tags: javascript

I need to sort words inside my `<p></p>` tags, so when I do :

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
```

I get HTML collection.

At this point, I do not know how to proceed. How do I get a single paragraph from the collection and sort each of them?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: The down votes are b/c you need to show what you've tried up to this point and then post a small example of the failing code.

Comment: Sounds like homework

Comment: @ZachM. so a task I have a problem with I cannot ask a question here? Don't you have anything more interesting to do than to nag here?

Comment: Don't you have some code you could produce to show what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets trickier if you have html nested inside your `<p>` tags, but you could just split the text into an array of strings, then [sort the array](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp).

Here's a fiddle showing this in entirety: https://jsfiddle.net/tuc2d5f1/9/

Here's basic JS code. It does not account for html inside the nodes, and does no complex replacement of characters.

```
for (var i in paragraphs) {
    if (!paragraphs.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
    // skip this iteration if it's not an actual element

    console.log("Starting paragraph: " + i);
    var text = paragraphs[i].innerHTML.toString().toLowerCase(); 
    // get the text of the node

    text = text.trim().replace(".", ""); 
    // you need to remove special chars. Regex would be best

    var txtAry = text.split(" "); // split to an array based on spaces
    // you should first replace all newline / return chars with spaces

    txtAry.sort(); // this is an array of strings in alphabetical order

    console.log(txtAry);
}
```

Comment: I got that part, I am having trouble with forEach loop, getting all of the single paragraph tags innerHTML

Comment: @grabnem see my updated answer with a working fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` returns you an array-like object that contains HTML collections. You need to loop through these items and extract html from it

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var html;
for (var i=0; i<paragraphs.length; i++) {
  /* cache plain string */
  html = paragraphs[i].innerHTML
  /* convert into an array, sort it as an array, convert back to string */
  html = html.split('').sort().join('');
  console.log(html);
}
```

Comment: I tried that already and it doesn't seem to work, it doesn't enter the loop at all, there is no log, thanks for the answer though

Comment: Please follow this example: [solution](http://jsbin.com/tosucohaqe/edit?html,js,console,output) - Is that what are you looking for?

Comment: It is close, the answer below is more to what I was looking for, but thanks for the answer!